# unable to cast the object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In my c# winforms, I am binding Data to DropDownList from a DataTable. The data is visible in the form, but I am not able to get the SelectedValue of this DropDownList.

If I access the SelectedValue then it shows this error:

```
unable to cast the object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type System.IConvertible.
```

and the application closes.

There are two or three other DropDownList bound in the same way and they are all are working fine.

The code for the DropDownList is:

```
LstDriverName.DisplayMember = "DriverName";
LstDriverName.ValueMember = "Driverid";
DriverDetail Driverdetails = new DriverDetail(Constr);
LstDriverName.DataSource = Driverdetails.SelectAllNames();
```

Here Driverdetails.SelectAllNames() returns a DataTable.

If I check the value in the immediate window:

```
?LstDriverName.SelectedValue.ToString()
"System.Data.DataRowView"
```

and the place where the message shows is:

```
NewBill = new TransportationBill(Constr);
NewBill.DriverId = Convert.ToInt32(LstDriver.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: What does `SelectAllNames()` return?  It's very odd that the selected value should be a reference to a `DataRowView` object, but if it is then that would certainly lead to the error you're receiving when you try to pass it to anything in `System.Convert`.

Comment: DisplayMember and ValueMember are case sensitive..

Comment: I bet that would be the problem here. As `ValueMember` does not match due to the case sensitivity, the `SelectedValue` returns the actual objects in collection, not the values extraced from the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
NewBill = new TransportationBill(Constr);
NewBill.DriverId = Convert.ToInt32(LstDriver.SelectedValue.Item["Driverid"]);
```

Still, it is very strange that you are getting items of type  `System.Data.DataRowView`

Answer (score -1):

Since you have bound to a DataTable, the individual items are of type `DataRowView`. These are very similar to a `DataRow`: they have columns which contain your data.

It makes no sense for you to try to convert an entire row of data to an integer. What you probably want is something more like this:

```
var selectedRow = (DataRowView) LstDriver.SelectedValue;
NewBill.DriverId = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow["Driverid"]);
```

You want to convert the "Driverid" column of the selected row, not the entire row.

In fact, if the "Driverid" column is already an integer, then you don't need to convert it. Instead:

```
NewBill.DriverId = (int) selectedRow["Driverid"];
```